# Average number of records by ID

Tags: pandas, python-3.x

I have a dataframe with IDs and booking refs, looking like the simplified example below.

| ID | BookingRef |
| --- | --- |
| 001 | 2019/32323 |
| 002 | 2011/23232 |
| 002 | 2017/7u4922 |

In the above example, 001 has one booking and 002 has two bookings in total so the average number of bookings for customers is 1.5.

How could I calculate this for millions of records using python and pandas?

Comment: This question belongs in stack overflow

Comment: I'm affraid it doesn't even belon to SO as it would be a duplicate (or low effort) ... correct answer would be to suggest a data analysis course (I'd suggest kaggle course) so that op learn about pandas groupby.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) method to group the dataframe by ID, then [`size()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.size.html) to count the number of rows for each ID.  Then use the [`mean`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mean.html) function to get the average:

```py
df.groupby('ID').size().mean()
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to count the number of rows per ID, another way is to use `value_counts()`.

```py
df['ID'].value_counts().mean()
# 1.5
```